# Excel spreadsheet missing a reference sheet name

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-chart

I inherited an Excel spreadsheet.

It houses about 80 graphs.  I am missing the sheet name *draft* that is referenced.  There is not a sheet named *draft* with hide or unhide yet all these graphs reference that sheet name. Here is a sample of the graph data.

> =SERIES(Draft!$BE$214:$BE$215,Draft!$BB$216:$BB$236,Draft!$BE$216:$BE$236,3).

I wrote a 1 line code of VBA that will unhide *draft* and the code errors, ie the sheet name is not here.  There are no hidden sheets, specifically, there are no hidden sheets named *draft*.

Can someone point me toward a surprising and wonderful solution, please?

I have a bad feeling that was an external spreadsheet that has disappeared and I will get to recreate all the graphs.

Comment: Do you know what the source data looked like?

Comment: Does it graph correctly? Does it prompt to update _Links_? If the source sheet is deleted, it should've shown `#Ref` error in the formula. If it is external, it should've shown the external address. Can you show a screen shot of the VBA environment? If the _draft_ sheet exist, VBA project explorer won't miss it. Also what line of code did you try in VBA. This should work: `Worksheets("Draft").Visible = xlSheetVisible`

Comment: If it's graphing correctly then it's possible your VBA line had a typo (maybe "draft" instead of "Draft"). Just blanket bomb the thing in case there are any other lurking sheets too: `Dim ws as Worksheets`|`For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`|`ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible`|`Next`

Comment: Probably sheet `Draft` has its visibility set to `xlSheetVeryHidden`.